# Find html element which id starts with 

Tags: jquery

my question is this:

I have HTML code in multiple pages, on each of them I used a JQgrid (jquery grid) for display some data. I knew that on each of those pages, the element that holds the JQgrid is named as "LIST_xxx". Now I need to make a javascript that takes that element "LIST_XXXX" on each page and does some stuff. How could I search for an element by ID but only knowing its initial part (of the ID ,like i mentioned previously):

```
$('#list_[XXXX]')... --> The part surrounded by [] is variable on each page, i want to discriminate that.
```

I hope i made myself clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Try

```
$('div[id^="list_"]')
```

It should work

Comment: Much better layout on that reference than the jquery documentation.

Comment: This works fine thanks... I used it to find an id that end with specific value like if($('div[id$="'+val+'"]').length > 0) execute something;

Comment: well, Its working well for above simple IDs of controls. How to make it work for scenarios like I am having controls with such IDs "txt_0_city" , "txt_1_city" , "txt_2_city" , "txt_3_city" and so on, and I want the count of all such elements having IDs like "txt_*_city"

Comment: @Rajiv if you have control over the html, it would be good to add a class like "city" to each of those elements. You can then easily count them.

Comment: @Rajiv if you can't improve the html, then check out https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ - you can combine the selectors. For example, $("span[id^='txt_'][id$='_city']")

Answer (score 26):

You need to use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector), like this:

```
$('[id^=list_]').whatever()
```

Comment: well, Its working well for above simple IDs of controls. How to make it work for scenarios like I am having controls with such IDs "txt_0_city" , "txt_1_city" ,   "txt_2_city" ,  "txt_3_city" and so on,  and I want the count of all such elements having IDs like "txt_*_city"

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, welcome to stackoverflow. I've responded to the other copy of your comment.

Answer (score 8):

Give that element a common class name or some other attribute you can query for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem with your suggestion is that there might be multiple tables holding JQgrid, so there could be: "LIST_customer", "LIST_carrier"... and so on. And I need to select both of them basen only on the initial ID part: "LIST_".

Comment: I understand, but making them all a List class seems like a more readable and descriptive approach to me. To each his own, you could always use the starts with selector in jquery as shown by other answers.

Comment: @lidermin What Yuriy says should work. Why dont you add a class to your controls such as "list" since you have list_ as your prefix. so when you select that class it will get each of those controls. This will be the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Yuriy's answer will work.  You can add the same class (for example "ListsINeedToFind") to all your "LIST_XXXX" elements, and then look them up using `$('.ListsINeedToFind')`.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to have multiple elements with the same class but different IDs.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "attribute starts with" selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("[id^=list_]")
```

Be aware that this is inefficient. Prefix with the tag name and descend from the nearest parent if possible.

Answer (score 3):

To get an element ending with a certain id/character

```
find('[id$=someid]')
```

To get an element starting with a certain id/character

```
find('[id*=anotherid]')
```

To get an element matching with a certain id/character

```
find('[id^=id]')
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Just returns false on every statement

Comment: @AmitSharma Can you please post your command here? And what are you trying to query?