# jQuery Mobile page instantly going back after changing pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-listener

So I am having a very hard time with some click events on a specific page of my site. I have a dashboard creation tool that brings the user back to the same page 4 times in a row while selecting their options/charts. By the fourth time the user returns to make their final selection every time they click the next button it jumps back to the page the click even originated from 4 times before allowing the button click to change the page properly. I know that event handlers are supposed to be used in the pagecreate event and mine are located there but they still fire multiple times. I have even tested it with stopPropagation but that isnt the issue from how I understand the problem and it doesnt do anything. Here are the event listeners

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#mobile-newdash',function(){

    $('#builder-two').click(function(){
      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true
});

    });
    $('#builder-three').click(function(){
      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true
});
    });
    $('#builder-four').click(function(){
      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true
});
    });
```

});

And here is the html

```
 <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin:0; padding:0; overflow-y:none;">
  <div id="newdash-grid">
  <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
  <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" id="block-one-newdash" style="background-color:white;">
    <p style="text-align:center; color:black; font-size:150%;">Select a chart to complete your custom dashboard.</p><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li class="premade-button-class"><a href="#mobile-chartmenu" class="ui-btn-active" id="premade-one">Premade Charts</a></li><li class="builder-button-class"><a href="#" id="builder-one">Chart Builder</a></li></ul></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" id="block-two-newdash">
    <p style="text-align:center; color:black; font-size:150%;">Select a chart to complete your custom dashboard.</p><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li class="premade-button-class"><a href="#mobile-chartmenu" class="ui-btn-active" id="premade-two">Premade Charts</a></li><li class="builder-button-class"><a href="#" id="builder-two">Chart Builder</a></li></ul></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" id="block-three-newdash">
    <p style="text-align:center; color:black; font-size:150%;">Select a chart to complete your custom dashboard.</p><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li class="premade-button-class"><a href="#mobile-chartmenu" class="ui-btn-active" id="premade-three">Premade Charts</a></li><li class="builder-button-class"><a href="#" id="builder-three">Chart Builder</a></li></ul></div>
  </div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" id="block-four-newdash">
    <p style="text-align:center; color:black; font-size:150%;">Select a chart to complete your custom dashboard.</p><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li class="premade-button-class"><a href="#mobile-chartmenu" class="ui-btn-active" id="premade-four">Premade Charts</a></li><li class="builder-button-class"><a href="#" id="builder-four">Chart Builder</a></li></ul></div>
  </div></div></div></div>
  <div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" id="clear-btn">Clear Dashboard</a></li><li><a href="#" id="save-btn">Save Dashboard</a></li></ul></div>
```

What confuses me the most is that the use of an href anchored link in li  also has the same problem. I cant just link the page using that because it still bounces back 4 times on the 4th chart selection.

Any help will be much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the question [Find html element which id starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298730/find-html-element-which-id-starts-with)  you should use this:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#mobile-newdash',function(){
    $('a[id^="builder-"]').off('click');
    $('body').on('click','a[id^="builder-"]',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
            transition: 'flip',
            changeHash: false,
            reverse: true
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't stop jQuery mobile from creating an even listener everytime it comes back to the page. But I don't think I'll ever rewrite an event listener multiple times again after seeing your code so thanks for that!

Comment: @NateGreene, you're right. Please, check my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `.unbind()` to avoid multiple clicks and try others too if it does not work

```
  $('#builder-three').unbind().click(function(){
      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true
});
```

> OR

```
  var counter=0;
  $('#builder-three').click(function(){
  if(counter<=0){
      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true
  }
});
```

> OR

```
$('#builder-three').one('click', function () { 

          $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#mobile-chartmenu-chartbuilder', {
        transition: 'flip',
        changeHash: false,
        reverse: true

    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do the trick either. I have tried the off() on() route as well with the same results.

Comment: None of these options worked. While the counter did successfully disable the click event the page still instantly returned to the page where the listener was called from.