# how to Concatenate an id in a foreach loop using jquery laravel

Tags: php, jquery

i have a foreach loop whereby i want to concatenate the id of each loop to its id jquery.i have tried this but i get the the id for the first loop only.this is my code in the blade file.

```
 @foreach ($rentalcategories as $category)
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="text" value="{{ $category->id }}" class="catid">
    <input type="radio" name="rentalcategory" class="rentalcattitle" id="rentalcat{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->id }}">
        <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label"> {{ $category->rentalcat_title }}</label><span>({{ $category->rentalhses->count() }})</span>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

this is my jquery code

```
var categoryid=$(".catid").val();
console.log(categoryid);
var hsecategory= $('#rentalcat' + categoryid).prop('checked') ? $('#rentalcat' + categoryid).value : ''
```

on the console logging the categoryid variable am only getting the first value only for the first loop but the other one it doesn't show.how can i get the id for each loop then concatenate to an id in each loop.
here in my code i want to get the value for each loop using the id instead of class.how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the Id as incrementing within the loop you just need to find element by id that starts with rentalcat

so something like this

```
$('input[id^="rentalcat"]')
```

credit to : [Find html element which id starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298730/find-html-element-which-id-starts-with)

that should give all the instances so you will need to preform an each function to get out each instance value

```
$('input[id^="rentalcat"]').each(function( i ) {
   console.log($(this).val())
});
```

you can then concatenate that values or do whatever you need with the id's in the each loop

I hope this helps